# touchesMoved continued point?

Tags: ios, ipad, touchesmoved

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

NSLog("%f  %f",currentPoint.x,currentPoint.y);
}
```

i want to developed a paint app for my ipad.
when i use these code and use finger to paint a line on my pad,
it's print
(x,1),(x,3),(x,6),(x,7),(x,12),(x,15),(x,18)....

in my thought,it should print
(x,1),(x,2),(x,3),(x,4),(x,5),(x,6),(x,7),(x,8),(x,9),(x,10),(x,11),(x,12),(x,13),(x,14),(x,15),(x,16),(x,17),(x,18)....

touchesMoved can not get continued coordinate ?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the speed that you swipe.
If you swipe really slow you'll probably get (x,1),(x,2),(x,3),(x,4),(x,5),(x,6),(x,7),(x,8),(x,9),(x,10), but if you swipe fast you can get as little as (x,1),(x,5),(x,10).

If you are developing a paint app you will have to take into account if the user hasn't lift his finger and paint the line between the points if he hasn't.

Good luck!

Comment: if i get (1,1),(10,5),(1,10)，the line i paint on the screen doesn't look smart.user maybe want to paint a arc,but i draw a line on the screen.

Comment: Don't forget that this numbers are pixels, if you swipe fast you might skip some but not enough to make an arc look like a line. You can check the iphone app "Handwritting" (also runs on ipad and it's free) and see the effect that occurs when you swipe really fast.